# sudo apt-get install -f doesn't fix broken packages. And now?

Tags: package-management, cinelerra

`$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for ...: 
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências

Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Corrigindo dependências... Pronto
Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:
  python-pyasn1 libconfig++8 python-twisted-runner linux-headers-3.0.0-12
  libvamp-sdk2 python-twisted-mail libgnomecanvasmm-2.6-1c2a
  python-twisted-lore python-twisted-conch python-twisted-news
  python-twisted-words python-twisted libffado2 linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic
  libaubio2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' para removê-los.
Os pacotes extra a seguir serão instalados:
  libmpeg3cine
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  libmpeg3cine
0 pacotes atualizados, 1 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 0 não atualizados.
2 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
É preciso baixar 0 B/2.573 kB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 6.762 kB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar [S/n]? S
(Lendo banco de dados ... 317732 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
Desempacotando libmpeg3cine (de .../libmpeg3cine_1%3a2.2-0.3~ppa1~oneiric1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: erro processando /var/cache/apt/archives/libmpeg3cine_1%3a2.2-0.3~ppa1~oneiric1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 a tentar sobre-escrever '/usr/bin/mpeg3cat', que também está no pacote mpeg3-utils 1.5.4-5ubuntu1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmpeg3cine_1%3a2.2-0.3~ppa1~oneiric1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

.....:~$ apt-get autoremove
E: Não foi possível abrir arquivo de trava /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permissão negada)
E: Não foi possível travar o diretório administrativo (/var/lib/dpkg/), você é root?

Comment: Well, the last command requires elevated privileges, so prepend sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following commands:

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-all
 sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get update
```