# Can't install new packages because of libssl broken dependencies

Tags: 12.04, apt

I can't install any new package either using apt-get or via the package manager. Below is some output showing the error. Please help!

```
pauldb@pauldb-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.6) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.7 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
pauldb@pauldb-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-29 linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic python-support
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,525 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
```

---

sudo apt-get update doesn't fix the problem:

```
pauldb@pauldb-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for pauldb: 
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                                          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                                    
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                                       
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]                                                                
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]                                                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                                                                        
Get:4 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]                                                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                                                     
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]                                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                                           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                                                  
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]                                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                   
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                                               
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise InRelease                                 
Get:7 http://linux.dropbox.com precise Release.gpg [489 B]                     
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]                                                   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB                                                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                            
Get:9 http://linux.dropbox.com precise Release [2,603 B]                       
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB]                           
Get:11 http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main amd64 Packages [1,148 B]                                
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en     
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com precise/main Translation-en
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources [155 kB]                                                                           
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages [1,273 kB]                                                                        
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages [8,452 B]                                                                   
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages [4,786 kB]                                                                    
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages [119 kB]                                                                    
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex [3,706 B]                                                                       
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex [2,676 B]                                                                 
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex [2,596 B]                                                                 
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex [2,922 B]                                                                   
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [368 kB]                                                                         
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [5,135 B]                                                                  
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [79.3 kB]                                                                    
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [4,729 B]                                                                  
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [584 kB]                                                                  
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [9,565 B]                                                           
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [182 kB]                                                              
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [9,436 B]                                                           
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3,564 B]                                                               
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [2,605 B]                                                         
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [2,461 B]                                                         
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2,850 B]                                                           
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [64.0 kB]                                                                       
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [1,950 B]                                                                 
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [22.2 kB]                                                                   
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1,388 B]                                                                 
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [230 kB]                                                                 
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [3,969 B]                                                          
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [68.2 kB]                                                            
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2,188 B]                                                          
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]                                                                 
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [71 B]                                                           
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [71 B]                                                           
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]                                                             
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB [96.4 kB]                                                                      
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en [726 kB]                                                                          
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_GB [79.8 kB]                                                                
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en [93.4 kB]                                                                   
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_GB [2,406 B]                                                                
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en [2,395 B]                                                                   
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_GB [5,492 B]                                                                  
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en [3,341 kB]                                                                    
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_GB [96.4 kB]                                                              
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [260 kB]                                                                  
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_GB [79.8 kB]                                                        
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [5,694 B]                                                           
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_GB [2,406 B]                                                        
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,328 B]                                                           
Get:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_GB [5,492 B]                                                          
Get:62 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [108 kB]                                                              
Get:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [112 kB]                                                                 
Get:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [995 B]                                                            
Get:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en [978 B]                                                            
Get:66 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [43.2 kB]                                                            
Fetched 19.2 MB in 1min 29s (214 kB/s)                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done
pauldb@pauldb-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-29 linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic python-support
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,525 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libssl-dev amd64 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.7 [1,525 kB]
Fetched 1,525 kB in 7s (214 kB/s)                                                                                                              
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
pauldb@pauldb-laptop:~$
```

---

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: Have you tested `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: It doesn't. I added the console output to the initial question.

Comment: type `sudo apt-get install libssl` and then hit `Tab` to see what you got there

Comment: Hitting `Tab` doesn't autocomplete with anything.

Comment: Give use the contents of your repositories.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: give us the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Updated the question with the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I followed the answer proposed in:
[sudo apt-get install -f doesn't fix broken packages. And now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96129/sudo-apt-get-install-f-doesnt-fix-broken-packages-and-now)

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-all

 sudo apt-get clean

 sudo apt-get update
```

It fixed the problem for me.

Comment: good bless you!

Comment: In addition to HecThor's answer, I had to run sudo apt-get -f install afterwards.